# Как создать исполняемый jar файл ScalaFX?

Tags: jar, scala, sbt

Есть такой пример, при команде

```
sbt run
```

он выполняется, без замечаний. При команде

```
sbt package
```

создается `jar` файл. При попытке запустить `jar` выскакивает ошибка:

> Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again.

Scala version: `2.12.4`. JVM: `1.8.0_152`. ScalaFX: `8.0.102-R11`

*hello.scala:*

```
package hello

import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color._
import scalafx.scene.shape.Rectangle

object HelloStage extends JFXApp {

    stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
        title.value = "Hello Stage"
        width = 600
        height = 450
        scene = new Scene {
            fill = LightGreen
            content = new Rectangle {
                x = 25
                y = 40
                width = 100
                height = 100
                fill <== when(hover) choose Green otherwise Red
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*build.sbt:*

```
name := "Scala"

   organization := "scalafx.org"

   version := "1.0.5"

   scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

   scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Xcheckinit", "-
   encoding", "utf8")

   resourceDirectory in Compile := (scalaSource in Compile).value

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.102-R11",)

   addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross 
   CrossVersion.full)

   fork := true
```

Comment: попробуйте sbt assembly. чуть позже напишу более детально, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить project/plugins.sbt:

`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")`

Это загрузит sbt-plugin.

Изменить build.sbt:

```
name := "Scala"

organization := "scalafx.org"

version := "1.0.5"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Xcheckinit", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.102-R11"

fork := true

mainClass in assembly := Some("hello.HelloStage")
```

Чтобы создать jar файл необходимо выполнить

```
sbt> assembly
```

Всё работает